# Show that the transformation $T(p(x))= p'(x) + p''(x)$ is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Say you have a transformation of $P_{3}$  to $P_{3}$  defined by, say, $T(p(x))= p'(x) + p''(x)$ where $p'(x)$ and $p''(x)$ are the first and second derivate. 
How would you determine if this is diagonalizable?

Do I sub in a standard basis of {$1,x,x^{2},x^{3}$} as p(x) and construct a matrix with each result?

Comment: Choose $x^i/i!$ as your basis.

Comment: We have $T^4 = 0$ (why?). Can such a matrix be diagonalizable? To see that this is not the case, assume that you have a matrix $A$ with $A^2 = 0$. Suppose now that it is diagonalizable, i.e., there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that $A = SDS^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal. What is $A^2$ then? Why can such a $D$ not exist? Now, do the same stuff for $T^4 = 0$ above.

Comment: @Friedeich Philipp: you forgot to say the maps $A$ and $T$ aren't themselves the zero operator.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Well, $T$ is obviously not zero, but $A$ should be assumed to be non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

We wish to determine if the linear map $T: P_3\to P_3$ given by
$T(p)=p^\prime+p^{\prime\prime}$ is diagonalizable.

In general this can be
checked by choosing a basis $\beta$ for $P_3$ and determining if the matrix
$[T]_\beta^\beta$ is diagonalizable.

You have chosen the basis
$\beta=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$. To compute $[T]_\beta^\beta$, note that
\begin{array}{rcccrcrcrcrcrcr}
  T(1)   & = & 0           & = & \color{blue}{0}\cdot 1 &+& \color{red}{0}\cdot x &+& \color{green}{0}\cdot x^2 &+& \color{purple}{0}\cdot x^3 \\
  T(x)   & = & 1           & = & \color{blue}{1}\cdot 1 &+& \color{red}{0}\cdot x &+& \color{green}{0}\cdot x^2 &+& \color{purple}{0}\cdot x^3 \\
  T(x^2) & = & 2+2\,x      & = & \color{blue}{2}\cdot 1 &+& \color{red}{2}\cdot x &+& \color{green}{0}\cdot x^2 &+& \color{purple}{0}\cdot x^3 \\
  T(x^3) & = & 6\,x+3\,x^2 & = & \color{blue}{0}\cdot 1 &+& \color{red}{6}\cdot x &+& \color{green}{3}\cdot x^2 &+& \color{purple}{0}\cdot x^3 
\end{array}
This shows that 
$$
[T]_\beta^\beta
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \color{blue}{0}   & \color{blue}{1}   & \color{blue}{2}   & \color{blue}{0}  \\
  \color{red}{0}    & \color{red}{0}    & \color{red}{2}    & \color{red}{6}   \\
  \color{green}{0}  & \color{green}{0}  & \color{green}{0}  & \color{green}{3} \\
  \color{purple}{0} & \color{purple}{0} & \color{purple}{0} & \color{purple}{0}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Is this matrix diagonalizable?